# How can i perform a keyword search for all the public feeds in facebook via FB api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-public-feed-api

A Keyword search which helps to give me all the recent feeds.
I found the graph api - search

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/examples/

but i dont know to use them!
all i tried was

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?";
        $graph_url .= "&type=post";
        $graph_url .= "&q=$keyword";
        $results = file_get_contents( $graph_url );
        $json = json_decode($results);
        foreach($json->data as $show ) {
        echo $show->from->name . "<br />";
        echo $show->message . "<br />";
        echo $show->created_time . "<br />";
        echo "<hr>";
        }
```

Stilll i get errors like
Warning : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden